# RecyclerView scroll to desired position without animation

Tags: android

Previously, when I want to scroll a `ListView` to a desired position, I will use

```
listView.setSelection(row);
```

The `ListView` will be scrolled without any animation - [Android List View set default position without animation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5497125/72437)

Now, I want to achieve the same effect on `RecyclerView`. I try to perform

```
((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(row, 0);
```

However, there is scrolling animation, which I would like to avoid.

Is there any way I can perform programmatically scrolling, without animation?

This is the animation I meant - https://youtu.be/OKsUKwBLoks

Note, I had already tried the following ways. All of them do generate animation.

- scrollToPositionWithOffset
- smoothScrollToPosition
- scrollToPosition

Comment: The video you posted shows an item insertion animation, which has nothing to do with the scroll animation.

Comment: @BladeCoder Sorry. Will revise the video in later time to avoid confusion.

Comment: Is a mistake. The animation is caused by the add operation, not scroll operation itself. Hence, this is an invalid question by itself. Sorry for confusion caused.

Comment: This is a valid question. `ScrollToPosition()` triggers `AnimateAdd()` in `DefaultItemAnimator`. Should be re-open.

Answer (score 16):

I know I'm a little late with this answer but it may help someone else. 
Try following (at least I could not see any animation when using it):

## Kotlin:

```
    //-- Immediately jump to the position in RecyclerView without delay or animation.
    mRecyclerView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position)
            mRecyclerView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        }
    })
```

## Java:

```
mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
            mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
});
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks.

Comment: Others are now working. This is working for my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line in your layout.xml

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

**EDIT:**

Another way to scroll recycleview

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

Comment: I thought android:overScrollMode only meant for ScrollView? I tested on RecyclerView, it makes no difference. Scrolling animation is still there.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng i edited my answer i added the other method to scroll a recycleview, try it

Comment: it doesn't work. smooth scroll will perform scrolling animation.

Answer (score 2):

You can scroll without animation with:

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be re-produced easily when you calling `notifyItemInserted()` with `scrollToPosition()` at same time.

Animation is caused by `DefaultItemAnimator` in RecyclerView default item animator class.

I found [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1drp1Xk8j0k) that re-produced problem by other person.

And I has solution too:

- First, scroll to last position with `scrollToPosition()`.
- Second, wait a little bit to let layout manager to finish scrolling.
- Third, add item into your adapter data set.
- Fourth, calling `notifyItemInserted()` and `scrollToPosition()` now.

I have code example but written in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) , but it does same to [[image]kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) with lambda expression. If you need accessing RecyclerView inside Adapter, you might want to look into `Adapter.onAttachedToRecyclerView()`.

```
if (Adapter.ListData.Count > 2) Adapter.RecyclerView.ScrollToPosition(Adapter.ListData.Count - 1);
Adapter.RecyclerView.PostDelayed(() =>
{
    Adapter.ListData.Add(new ItemSimplyfiedAdapter.Standard
    {
       //Some new item inserting into data set.
    });
    Adapter.NotifyItemInserted(Adapter.ListData.Count - 1);
    Adapter.RecyclerView?.ScrollToPosition(Adapter.ListData.Count - 1);
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

As **@nyconing** said in the comments, this behavior is caused by the default `ItemAnimator` attached to the recycler view. Just remove it!

```
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```